# javascript object property has pointer to another property

Tags: javascript

I have this code, wich adds Node to array and then changes it, the `firstNode` object is set in the `init` function.

```
var myClass = function() {
    this.items = []
    this.firstNodeValues = {};

    this.init = function() {
        var firstIndex = false;

        for (i = 10; i <= 15; i++) {
            Node = {};
            Node.index = i;
            Node.name = "undefined";
            if (i == 10) {
                Node.name = "John"
                this.firstNodeValues = Node;
            }
            this.items[i] = Node;
        }
    }

    this.iterate = function() {
        var newIndex = 10;
        for (i = 10; i <= 15; i++) {
            this.items[i].index = newIndex;
            if (i == 10) {
                this.items[i].name = "Michael";
            }
            newIndex++;
        }
    }
}
var test = new myClass();
test.init();
console.debug(test.firstNodeValues.name) // this gives value "John"
test.iterate();
console.debug(test.firstNodeValues.name) // this gives value "Michael"
```

The second debug returns `"Michael"` but why? It looks the `firstNodeValues` has a pointer to the node `items[10]`.
I want that if I set the `FirstNodeValues` in `firstTime` and later a change Node values then the `firstNodeValues` is not Changes and stay exactly the same as I first set it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your clone is changing when you change your data is this:

```
this.firstNodeValues = Node;
```

There, you are declaring `firstNodeValues` to be a *reference* to `Node`, not a *copy*. So everything you change in `firstNodeValues`, changes in `Node`, and vice versa.

You'll need to clone the object, like this:

```
function clone(obj){
    if(obj == null || typeof(obj) != 'object'){
        return obj;
    }

    var temp = {};

    for(var key in obj){
        if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key))){
            temp[key] = clone(obj[key]);
        }
    }
    return temp;
}
```

Then, you can copy the node, like this:

```
this.firstNodeValues = clone(Node);
```

This will make sure that `this.firstNodeValues` isn't a reference to `Node`, but a new object, with the same properties / values as `Node` (So, a clone).

Comment: Could the person that down voted me please tell me why? If I made a mistake, I'd like to learn from it.

Answer (score -1):

You might be interested in [jQuery.extend()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/). So:

`this.firstNodeValues = $.extend( {}, Node );`

Comment: jQuery answer on a native JS question. OP didn't ask for JQ, doesn't seem to use it, and the answer doesn't explain why he might be interested in it.